# Is there anyway to disable default splash screen for android 12

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

*I want to add custom splash screen but before that the default splash screen displayed which looks too weird*

Comment: You can customize the default splash screen, I mean replacing the view instead of showing two.

Comment: At android 12 it takes app logo and displayed it to in center of the screen 
as they mentioned in the following link
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/splash-screen

Comment: I used https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash package for splash screen in my app, its very easy and fast to implement.

Comment: Already tried and getting same results
They mention

**Android 12 has a new method of adding splash screens, which consists of a window background, icon, and the icon background.**

The package provides Android 12 support while maintaining the legacy splash screen for previous versions of Android.

PLEASE NOTE: The splash screen may not appear when you launch the app from Android Studio. However, it should appear when you launch by clicking on the launch icon in Android.

Answer (score 5):

you can add this line:

```
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
```

in your style.xml file before close style tag.
it`s make your default android splash transparent!

Comment: You saved me. Just a comment for Cordova developers: The file is themes.xml and is in "res\values" when you open it with Android Studio to compile, and "platforms\android\app\src\main\res\values" from the root of the project. Just add this line without deleting existing ones.

Answer (score 0):

On Android tweleve(12), it's not possible to out of the splash screen. Only possible to customize it: icon, window background, and animation.

By default, the splash screen is shown from user touch until the first frame of your application is drawn, so to minimize the time during which the splash screen is shown, you can try to reduce the launch time of your application.

You can also implement you own exit animation so the transition from the splash screen to the app is more seamless.